# Simpler MongoDB / database alternative for node

Tags: json, node.js, storage

I need to permanently store some data in my application and so far I've been playing with MongoDB which however seems a little overkill for my purposes. So I'm looking for a simpler alternative:

- Easy setup; I would prefer if the storage was just a simple (JSON) file. What I especially don't like about Mongo is that it has to be separately installed and configured.
- Only one application will be accessing the database at one moment; no need for synchronization or access control (the whole database can be held in memory and only flushed to disk when changes occur)
- It should be asynchronous (it's Node, right...)
- Some basic querying and filtering over the data would be nice (like searching in collections, retrieving items by id etc.)

There are a lot of different solutions around but I haven't found one that would meet all my requirements. Most of the JSON databases I was able to find are just meant to be used on the client side and there doesn't seem to be any support for storing the data (asynchronously) to disk.

Could you recommend a solution?

Comment: May I ask for the reason of the down votes? I have a pretty straightforward problem and I'm looking for a solution. Either an existing module or a combination of existing modules. Or maybe I just need to be explained why my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After some further searching I discovered [warehouse](https://github.com/tommy351/warehouse/) which seems to be okay for my purpuses. It has a nice mongo-like API and supports writing and loading from a file. The documentation is concise and a little out-dated but one can learn all he need from the unit tests.

The database is completely kept in the memory which brings obvious limitations to the database size but I don't need to store large amounts of data.

The only problem was that the changes made to the database are not automatically saved. That means that if the app crashes before the database is saved manually, the changes are lost. Luckily, all models are event emitters so it is easy to detect changes and invoke saving.

This is approximately how my module handling the database looks like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var warehouse = require('warehouse');
var debug = require('debug')('db');
var _ = require('lodash');

function load() {
    db.load().then(function () {
        debug('Database loaded');
    })
}

// The promise will guarantee atomicity of writes to the disk so the database
// file will not get corrupted (as long as only one instance of this program is
// running at a time)
var savingPromise;
function save() {
    if (!savingPromise) {
        savingPromise = db.save();
    } else {
        savingPromise = savingPromise.then(db.save.bind(db));
    }
    savingPromise.then(function () {
        debug('Database saved');
    });
}

var databaseFile = 'database.json';
var db = new warehouse({path: databaseFile});
if (fs.existsSync(databaseFile)) {
    load();
}

var models = {
    Model1: db.model('model1', Model1Schema),
    Model2: db.model('model2', Model2Schema),
    Model3: db.model('model3', Model3Schema)
};

// Debouncing the save function ensures that if more than one change
// occur in a short period of time, they all will be saved with 
// in a single write to the disk. (Saving each change individually would
// significantly reduce the performance.)
var delayedSave = _.debounce(save, 1000);
_.each(models, function (model) {
    model.addListener('insert', delayedSave);
    model.addListener('update', delayedSave);
    model.addListener('remove', delayedSave);
});

module.exports = models;
```